# Can I use Nest iteration variable as the variable of Limit?

Tags: iteration

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this:

```
Limit[Nest[1/(1 + #) &, x0, n], n -> ∞]
```

Comment: The 3rd argument of `Nest` must be numeric

Comment: This `FixedPoint[1/(1 + #) &, #] & /@ Range[0., 4, 1]` might help.

Comment: Or for an exact value `x /. Solve[{1/(1 + x) == x, x > 0}, x][[1]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Nest` is a functional programming construct whereas `Limit` works primarily with mathematical expressions. It simply has no way to work with `Nest[...]`.

This can instead be handled by converting the nested expression into a solved recurrence.

```
recval = 
 RSolveValue[{f[n] == 1/(1 + f[n - 1]), f[0] == x0}, f[n], n]

(* Out[591]= ((2/(1 + Sqrt[5]))^
   n (-2^(1 - n) (1 - Sqrt[5])^n + 
     2^(1 - n) (1 + Sqrt[5])^n + (1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5]))^n x0 + 
     Sqrt[5] (1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5]))^n x0 - (1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]))^n x0 + 
     Sqrt[5] (1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]))^n x0))/(1 + Sqrt[
   5] - ((1 - Sqrt[5])/(1 + Sqrt[5]))^n + 
   Sqrt[5] ((1 - Sqrt[5])/(1 + Sqrt[5]))^n + 2 x0 - 
   2 ((1 - Sqrt[5])/(1 + Sqrt[5]))^n x0) *)
```

Since we are only really interested in integer `n` I will use `DiscreteLimit` on this.

```
dlim = DiscreteLimit[recval, n -> Infinity]

(* Out[592]= (2 + (-1 + Sqrt[5]) x0)/(1 + Sqrt[5] + 2 x0) *)
```

This is actually independent of initial value:

```
FullSimplify[dlim]

(* Out[610]= 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]) *)
```

Another well known way to deduce candidate values for the limit is to solve the fixed point equation.

```
Solve[x == 1/(1 + x), x]

(* Out[594]= {{x -> 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5])}, {x -> 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])}} *)
```

Comment: +1 You get the same result with `Limit[recval, n -> Infinity] // FullSimplify`. Also, it is useful to include `FullSimplify` in definition of `recval`